# Call a function in imported child component on click from a parent element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is it possible to call a function in an imported component from "parent element"? Because I have a few modules that I wanna have in my app and show them dynamically in my app. I though if I import a component like `Header` in my main `App.vue` folder it will recognize the function from the main `App.vue` folder.

Example of `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="m-grid m-grid--hor m-grid--root m-page">
        <!-- <loader></loader> -->
        <mobile-menu-partial></mobile-menu-partial>
        <header-partial></header-partial>
            <div :is="currentComponent"></div>
            <div v-show="!currentComponent" v-for="component in componentsArray" :key="component.id">
                <button @click="swapComponent(component)">{{component}}</button>
            </div>
            <button @click="swapComponent(null)">Close</button>
        <footer-partial></footer-partial>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Loader from '@/components/partials/Loader.vue'
import MobileMenu from '@/components/partials/MobileMenu.vue'
import Header from '@/components/partials/Header.vue'
import Footer from '@/components/partials/Footer.vue'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      currentComponent: null,
      componentsArray: ['dashboard', 'schedule', 'locations', 'mileage']
    }
  },
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    'loader': Loader,
    'mobile-menu-partial': MobileMenu,
    'header-partial': Header,
    'footer-partial': Footer
  },
  methods: {
    swapComponent: function (component) {
      console.log('component', component)
      this.currentComponent = component
      if (component === null) {
        console.log('anywhere_main')
        this.$router.push('/')
      } else {
        this.$router.push('/' + component)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

So can I have access of the function `swapComponent` in my `header-partial`? Because there are my modules for opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Calling child component's method from parent component

Say you have a `child-comp` component and want to call its `childMethod` method from the parent.

Use `ref="someVariableName"` on the parent's template and  `this.$refs.someVariableName` on the parent's JavaScript.

Parent's template:

```
<div id="app>
   <child-comp ref="myChild"></child-comp>
   <button @click="callChildMethod">GO</button>
</div>
```

Parent's JavaScript code:

```
{
  data: // ...
  // ...
  methods: {
    callChildMethod: function () {
      this.$refs.myChild.childMethod();
    }
}
```

## Calling parent's method from child

Emit an event in `<child-comp>` and listen to it in parent.

Parent's template (listening to an event):

```
<div id="app>
   <child-comp @eventname="parentsMethod"></child-comp>
</div>
```

Notice that `@eventname="parentsMethod"` is the same as `v-on:eventname="parentsMethod"`.

Parent's JavaScript code:

```
{
  data: // ...
  // ...
  methods: {
    parentsMethod: function (event) {
      console.log('parent called', event);
    }
}
```

Child's JavaScript code:

```
{
  data: // ...
  // ...
  methods: {
    someChildMethod: function () {
      this.$emit('eventname', {some: 'object value'});
    }
}
```

Now whenever, at the child, you call `someChildMethod` it will trigger the event and, since the parent is listening to it, it will execute `parentsMethod` in the parent.

Comment: In the JS Code section, that method is in child or parent component? But i want to have a function in parent component and then set a click in child component to call that parent function. So i have a swapComponent() function and i want to call that function when i click on some button from the imported comnponent. Do i need to set the 'ref' then on that imported component in the imported file or?

Comment: And then if i have a button in my child component i can say `<button @click="parentsMethod()"></button>`. Or i set on click and call `someChildMethod`?

Comment: Inside child you must call `someChildMethod`, which should be defined in its `methods`.

Comment: Yes i made it now. Thanks a lot!